# Cannot inject ExternalContext or RequestParam in CDI @RequestScoped managed Bean

Tags: jboss, cdi, weld, jsf-2.3, java-ee-8

Searching around the web I found that it should be possible to @Inject some convenient JSF Objects into CDI beans, these objects should be Produced by JSF and exposed via Qualifiers in javax.faces.annotation.* (like @RequestMap or @SessionMap).

However, I am not being able to @Inject these resources into CDI Beans. Even injecting `ExternalContext` or `FacesContext` fails which, as stated in JSF 2.3-spec should be possible to @Inject as well as the following:

- javax.faces.application.ResourceHandler
- javax.faces.context.Flash
- **javax.servlet.http.HttpSession** <-- this one is working

```
@RequestScoped
public class SimpleRequestParamReportProvider implements ReportParamsProvider {
    @Inject // <-- FAILS
    ExternalContext externalContext;

    @Inject // <-- FAILS
    FacesContext facesContext;

    @Inject @RequestMap // <-- FAILS
    Map<String, Object> requestMap;

    @Inject // <-- WORKS
    HttpSession httpSession;
```

**Error shown at application startup:**

Unsatisfied dependencies for type FacesContext with qualifiers @Default
  at injection point [BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject report.SimpleRequestParamReportProvider.facesContext

I am using **JBoss EAP 7.2** which is JSF 2.3 compliant https://access.redhat.com/articles/113373

Has anyone else ran into this same issue? Is there something I am missing?

**EDIT**
Here is the WEB-INF/faces-config-xml I am using

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_3.xsd"
    version="2.3">
</faces-config>
```

**EDIT 2**: Injection of JSF objects is working once I add a @FacesConfig annotated java class:

```
@FacesConfig(version = FacesConfig.Version.JSF_2_3)
public class FacesActivator {}
```

Comment: This exception will be thrown when you're not actually using JSF 2.3+ (i.e. when you think that you're using JSF 2.3, but the environment/build actually isn't correctly configured as-is). The cause of this problem is however not visible in the information provided so far. So this question cannot be answered. One of probable causes is that you didn't install/activate JSF 2.3 in JBoss EAP 7.2. Another probable cause is that you forgot to set the JSF 2.3 flag in faces-config.xml and/or the `@FacesConfig` trigger.

Comment: Hi @BalusC. Thanks for answering! I updated my question with the faces-config.xml my application is using. Is there a flag I am missing in there to activate jsf 2.3?

Comment: @BalusC your comment pointed me to the right direction. I was not aware of the need for a ```@FacesConfig``` activator, which seems to have resolved the Injection problem. Is there a way to activate from faces-config.xml sparing the need for ```@FacesConfig```? Thanks.

Comment: Just to mention another way in case it helps someone, I was able to get `ExternalContext` by using `FacesContext`: `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext()`